# "Rimasta incinta": senso dell'espressione

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

In italiano diciamo cose come "sono rimasta incinta". L'uso del verbo *rimanere* mi fa pensare ad un qualcosa che afferisce alla sfera della non volontarietà. 
Usiamo però questa espressione sempre, anche quando la volontarietà è intesa! In (almeno alcune) altre lingue diremmo: *schwanger werden* (diventare), *become/get pregnant*...

Qual è il senso dell'uso di *rimanere*, e perché non utilizzare *diventare* invece? C'è un motivo storico/sociale per questa preferenza?

Comment: il concepimento naturale avviene sempre con una certa probabilità, spesso bassa. Di questo va tenuto conto nella spiegazione

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*Rimanere*" è un verbo molto antico, usato fin dagli inizi nella [letteratura italiana](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rimanere_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/) con significati quasi immutati nel tempo.

[Si usa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rimanere/) con lo stesso significato di "*restare*", «quando si vuol dare al discorso un’intonazione più sostenuta», e per trasmettere più esplicitamente «il senso della permanenza, della durata, della continuità» di una condizione che si è subìta.

È diffuso «con complemento predicativo o modale: rimanere sbalordito, soddisfatto, scontento, confuso; rimanere vedovo, orfano, ecc.; rimanere incinta; rimanere male, di stucco, in dubbio, senza soldi, al buio, ecc.; rimanere in vigore; rimanere d’accordo (anche assol.: rimaniamo così)».

Similmente si usa anche «come verbo copulativo […] quando il predicato è rappresentato da un participio passato in funzione verbale: è rimasto abbandonato da tutti; rimase mortalmente ferito; è rimasto ucciso sul colpo (in usi fam., anche assol. c’è rimasto sul colpo; e con immagine più cruda: è rimasto secco)».

In tutti questi casi mi sembra che la costante, oltre al permanere di una situazione nel tempo, è proprio l'involontarietà della condizione che si subisce: si può provare a rimanere incinte, nel senso che se ne possono agevolare le condizioni, ma non è detto che l'evento si verifichi, *è una cosa che succede*.

Temo che esprimere la intenzionalità di una gravidanza, nel senso moderno, non sia facile in Italiano, e sì, potrebbero esserci delle cause storico-sociali. Originariamente in latino "*[incinta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incinta1/)*" era "*inciens-entis*", "*gravida*" (aggettivo riferito ad animali); successivamente, verso il [VI secolo](http://www.etimo.it/?term=incinta), per [deformazione paretimologica](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_003.html), diventò "*incincta*", dal participio passato del verbo "*incingere*", "*donna con la cintura*" (per sostenere il peso) oppure, al contrario, da "*incincta, non cincta*", "*donna senza cintura*" (per non schiacciare l'addome): in ogni caso non un bel modo per esprimere il concetto. Lo stesso concetto di gravidanza non è per niente poetico: è la condizione di chi è, letteralmente, appesantita dal prodotto del concepimento.

Forse, anziché «sono rimasta incinta», si potrebbe dire «ho iniziato la gravidanza» o, più tecnicamente, forse più freddamente, «ho cominciato la gestazione», ma il rischio è che suoni un po' bizzarro. Un'altra alternativa potrebbe essere «ho concepito», implicando di essere in dolce attesa.

Con i cambiamenti sociali e dei costumi, forse un giorno una donna potrà dire, e sembrerà normale, «mi sono incinta», riesumando il [verbo "incingere"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incingere/) («Benedetta colei che ’n te s’incinse!»); o al contrario, usando un po' d'ironia, «mi son messa la cinta» o anche «mi son tolta la cinta»; oppure «son divenuta incinta»; o «son divenuta gravida», «mi sono ingravidata».

Comment: Toglierei il riferimento alla “cinta”. Perché perpetuare l'errore? `;-)`

Comment: Non mi è chiara la frase «rimanere incinta significa letteralmente rimanere senza cintura (o, al contrario, mettersi una cintura), non un bel modo per esprimere il concetto»: etimologicamente una donna “incinta” è appunto una donna che porta abiti sprovvisti di cintura. Che c'è che non va? (Poi una persona può anche essere “discinta”, ma quella è un'altra storia.)

Comment: @egreg: Ti riferisci a chi pensa che si dica “in cinta” invariabile (*“le donne in cinta”), vero? È duro a morire, temo...

Comment: OK, ho specificato. Inizialmente in latino classico era "inciens-entis" che poi è stato deformato in "incincta" (ovvero donna con la cintura o, al contrario, donna senza cintura).

Comment: Grazie, @randomatlabuser, non sapevo del “con la cintura”: chissà in che senso. Ma continuo ad avere il dubbio di perché lo consideri “non un bel modo”...

Comment: Non la trovo una bellissima parola (1) perché si tratta di una deformazione paretimologica di un aggettivo riferito perlopiù ad animali e (2) perché si riferisce alla gestazione per gli effetti rigonfianti (!) che questa ha sul corpo della donna. Lo stesso vale anche per l'inglese "pregnant", peggio che peggio, aggettivo che si dovrebbe usare solo per gli animali.

Comment: La storia del lessico (e di altri aspetti della lingua) è innegabilmente importante e interessante, ma le parole hanno la storia che hanno, e non sempre il loro uso attuale ne viene condizionato. Se dovessimo regolarci in base alle avventure di 1500 anni fa delle parole di oggi, non ne dovremmo usare quasi nessuna.  Da una parte siamo tanto attenti ai piccoli slittamenti semantici degli ultimi anni o mesi indotti dalle novità tecniche e sociali e dall'altra decidiamo in base a quello che succedeva nel 500 d.C.?

Comment: Tornando a quello che chiedeva @martina, è innegabile, anche dagli esempi riportati qui sopra, che gli usi moderni di “rimanere” si ritrovano spesso in locuzioni con un'accezione negativa (almeno 3/4 degli esempi: scontento, orfano, male, senza soldi...). Evidentemente avviare una gravidanza porta tuttora il retaggio di un momento non esattamente di massima libertà e autosufficienza per la donna...

Comment: Hai ovviamente ragione :-) Eppure una donna moderna non direbbe mai, consapevolmente, «*mi son gonfiata*» per dire che è in stato interessante :-)

Answer (score 3):

Mi pare che "rimanere X" in questo e simili contesti contenga l'idea di ritrovarsi nello stato X come effetto conclusivo di un evento o una catena di eventi trascorsi, e che in gran parte dei casi il verbo suggerisca anche uno stato stazionario se non definitivo (rimanere di sasso/attonito/squattrinato/in mezzo alla strada/col culo per terra/secco; ma anche in positivo: rimanere  contento/soddisfatto/sorpreso &c).

Non c'è, o c'è meno, questa idea di continuità col passato nel verbo "diventare", che allude piuttosto all'entrata in un nuovo stato o all'inizio di una nuova condizione, dunque casomai con occhio alle evoluzioni future (idea che manca in "rimanere".)

Mi pare che l'espressione "rimanere incinta" venga tradizionalmente usata  alludendo all'esito imprevisto di una relazione (giudicata) illecita; normalmente si direbbe "essere incinta" (dove la scelta del verbo "essere" sembra voler dimenticare  ogni rapporto causale con l'atto sessuale che evidentemente c'è stato --a parte il caso della Madonna, ben s'intende). Supponiamo però che ci interessi esattamente il nesso causale, ad esempio in relazione a una cura ormonale ginecologica. Una rapida ricerca su Google indica che in tal caso si usa "rimanere"; innegabilmente suona strano però.

Volendo cercare un motivo per questa preferenza, verrebbe da dire che una certa mentalità diffusa giudica l'atto del concepimento come peccaminoso  (c'è chi sostiene che è stato necessario inventare una religione apposta). Ricordo una anziana signora molto per bene che non usava mai l'espressione "nove mesi", giudicata sconveniente: diceva: "L'anno passato sono stata sulla Costa Azzurra per più di otto mesi e mezzo".

Comment: Grazie per la risposta circostanziata. Ho due osservazioni:  
1. Hai qualche fonte per l'affermazione che “rimanere incinta” si usi “tradizionalmente” con riferimento a “una relazione (giudicata) illecita”, e analogamente per le affermazioni dell'ultimo capoverso (oltre alle tue esperienze personali)?  
2. L'“Immacolata Concezione” non si riferisce a quello che sembri credere, bensì al fatto che Maria, figlia di un normalissimo rapporto carnale tra i suoi genitori, sarebbe nata priva del peccato originale.

Comment: 1. Mi riferisco alla mia esperienza 2. Giustissimo! Corretto.

Comment: Grazie, ma non ho capito che ricerca hai fatto su Google per la storia del nesso causale!

Comment: osservavo che nei siti di ginecologia l'espressione usata è quella: per es.: "dopo tre mesi di cura sono rimasta incinta", che a me personalmente suona strana. In effetti in buona parte la mia risposta si basa su impressioni personali, quindi non so quanto sia utile.